# Calling WSE service from a .net 3.5 application

Tags: web-services, wse

I am trying to call a .asmx (WSE) web service from a .net 3.5 application.

This is possible correct?
It seems when I add a web reference the API is completely different than when I add a reference in a .net 2.0 app.

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Add Web Reference button in the dialog displayed (Add service reference) to add a pre-3.0 style reference.

By default, when you add a service reference, VS will generate a class that uses WCF. It's not an issue but you might prefer to stick to the old style.

By the way, WCF is more flexible and unified approach to communication in .NET 3.0 onwards. You should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

If the obsolete WSE service uses any of the WS-* protocols, then you will not be able to call is by using a Web Reference. There is no support for WSE in Visual Studio 2008 or above.

You may be able to make it work using "Add Service Reference", which will create a WCF client. You may still have issues due to the fact that WSE implemented earlier versions of some of the protocols.